# Node not updated, skipping node save

Tags: chef-infra

I just installed a fresh copy of chef server, and configured chef dk locally. I am able to bootstrap a node, however unable to edit its attributes:

```
piousbox@piousbox-e7440:~/projects/rails-quick-start$ knife node list
lb_staging
piousbox@piousbox-e7440:~/projects/rails-quick-start$ knife node edit lb_staging
/tmp/knife-edit-20170520-8378-x0vg2r.json
Node not updated, skipping node save
```

I get a new empty file in my $EDITOR. Is this a mis-configuration issue?

knife -v gives me Chef version: 12.19.36

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... the problem was with $EDITOR configuration, in this particular case I needed to add this to my .chef/knife.rb:

```
# .chef/knife.rb
knife[:editor] = '/usr/bin/emacs'
```